# data.table fill NA by custom function and other cells

Tags: r, data.table, dtplyr

Assume we have a `data.table` like:

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(123666)


dt <- data.table(
  id = seq(1, 5), 
  sample1 = c(sample(c(NA, runif(2))), NA),      
  sample2 = c(NA, sample(c(NA, runif(3)))),    
  sample3 = c(sample(c(NA, runif(4))))      
)
```

```
dt
   id   sample1   sample2   sample3
1:  1        NA        NA 0.6387276
2:  2 0.9293370 0.1875354 0.2087892
3:  3 0.1528115        NA 0.7849779
4:  4        NA 0.6875024 0.3684756
5:  5        NA 0.4859773        NA
```

Its have many NA values, now, we want to fill it, typically, we can use following `syntax` to do

```
dt[is.na(dt)] <- 0
```

```
dt
   id   sample1   sample2   sample3
1:  1 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.6387276
2:  2 0.9293370 0.1875354 0.2087892
3:  3 0.1528115 0.0000000 0.7849779
4:  4 0.0000000 0.6875024 0.3684756
5:  5 0.0000000 0.4859773 0.0000000
```

However, if we want to fill `NA` with more complex rule, a custom function for example, `calc_data()`, to calc `NA`. This function need two input, just a example here, first is the   `id` value of NA value, secound is the colname or colname index of the cell.

```
# example, not real function
sample_value <- c(1, 3, 3)
names(sample_value) <- c('sample1', 'sample2', 'sample3')
calc_data <- function(sample, id) {
    na_calc <- id * 3 + sample_value[sample]
}
```

Now, it is possible to fill `NA` with this coustom function with data.table `syntax`. how to put its required value to `calc_data`

Comment: see ?nafill and ?setnafill

Comment: @MichaelChirico, I have checked `nafill`, I got that it can fill NA with more rule, but I am not known how  to use my own function with `nafill`. The tricky problem is that you need to call some external function through the position of the blank cell, that is, its column name and id, to complete the filling. How to avoid going through the cell one by one and use a more efficient syntax?

Comment: `set(x, is.na(x$col), "col", <replacement values>)` is the fully general approach

Comment: Yeah, this is a general task if you know the missing value in a certain place, but the problem is that in our problem, the value of NA must depend on its position in the table

Comment: Could you provide a concrete example of which NA values you want to replace?

Comment: Hi, sorry for confusing, I need to replace all `NA` value, However, the value used to replace NA is not fixed, as mentioned in the example, the replacement value is related to the sample name (column name or column index) and the corresponding value in the id column

Comment: I would like to explain its practical application, in the real case, dt is obtained by combining the output of multiple samples (from a software A) by the id column, where NA is discarded because it does not pass through the filtering of software A. But my downstream analysis requires a valid value instead of NA, I re-implement part of the algorithm in A in R, and I can recalculate this information by calling this new implementation and giving the sample name and id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps something like this could work

```
for(j in 2:4) set(dt, 
                  i = which(is.na(dt[[j]])), 
                  j = j, 
                  value = calc_data(j - 1, dt[which(is.na(dt[[j]])), "id"]))
```

output

```
   id    sample1    sample2    sample3
1:  1  0.8055845 6.00000000  0.2030456
2:  2  0.5705721 9.00000000  0.7954992
3:  3 10.0000000 0.09605308 12.0000000
4:  4 13.0000000 0.25545666  0.6506906
5:  5  0.8055845 0.51889032  0.8931946
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative that isn't as "efficient" as `set` (which is the fastest `data.table`-canonical way to work on its data), we can do

```r
dt
#       id sample1 sample2 sample3
#    <int>   <num>   <num>   <num>
# 1:     1      NA      NA   0.639
# 2:     2   0.929   0.188   0.209
# 3:     3   0.153      NA   0.785
# 4:     4      NA   0.688   0.368
# 5:     5      NA   0.486      NA

sample_value <- c(1, 3, 3)
names(sample_value) <- c('sample1', 'sample2', 'sample3')
fun <- function(x, samp) fcoalesce(x, calc_data(samp, id))
dt[, names(sample_value) := Map(fun, .SD, sample_value),
   .SDcols = names(sample_value)]
#       id sample1 sample2 sample3
#    <int>   <num>   <num>   <num>
# 1:     1   4.000   6.000   0.639
# 2:     2   0.929   0.188   0.209
# 3:     3   0.153  12.000   0.785
# 4:     4  13.000   0.688   0.368
# 5:     5  16.000   0.486  18.000
```

- `Map` is similar to `lapply` (call a `FUN`ction once for each element in the list `X`), but while `lapply` can operate only on one list, `Map` "zips" multiple lists/vectors together. In this case, if we were to unroll the `Map` into a sequence of expressions, we'd effectively get:

  ```
  fun(sample1, 1)
  fun(sample2, 3)
  fun(sample3, 3)
  ```

  (I used `fun` as a predefined function for clarity and breakout, though it could easily be used as an anonymous function in the call to `Map`, as in

  ```
  Map(function(x, samp) fcoalesce(x, calc_data(samp, id)), .SD, sample_value)
  ```
- `fcoalesce` returns (element-wise along vectors) the first non-`NA` value found. It takes one or more vectors (I'm using two above, three here for demo). For example,

  ```
  fcoalesce(c(1,2,NA), c(3,NA,4), c(NA,5,6))
  # [1] 1 2 4
  ```

  The `1,2` from the first argument are retained. The third position is `NA`, so it shifts to the third position in the second argument and finds `4`, so it returns that as the third. In this case, nothing in the third argument `c(NA,5,6)` is needed.

  Using `fcoalesce` here is effectively the same as

  ```
  fifelse(is.na(x), calc_data(samp, id), x)
  ```

  which can also be used in the function if you prefer.
- I'm (ab)using the names of `sample_value` to iterate (in `.SDcols`) and save (as `names(sample_values) :=`).